# Will installing XtraFinder make my system vulnerable?

Tags: finder, security

I am tempted to install XtraFinder on my mac because of all the features it provides but am worried that it may leave my system vulnerable to a security breach.

The installation dialog box says the following

> OS X 10.11 and later users should read about System Integrity Protection before installing.

I went to the link provided ([System Integrity Protection](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/sip.html)):

> You need to partially disable System Integrity Protection. I do not encourage you to disable System Integrity Protection. It makes your computer less safe.

The warning is something to do with code injection into Finder.

- Does this mean that only XtraFinder is allowed to inject into Finder?
- Will this allow some other code to wreak havoc on my system?
- Will   installing XtraFinder make my system vulnerable?

Comment: I guess the question is will the command csrutil enable - -without debug create any holes related to security.

Comment: Yes it will. Disabling SIP is global, so any application can inject code into Finder, modify system files etc. while SIP is disabled.

Answer (score -3):

Go ahead and follow the directions. When you finish, re-enable System Integrity Protection and restart.